# How is it possible to create some user defined filter options?

Tags: algorithm, search, filtering

Some system has a lot of lists, containing the groups of the repair stations with adresses, phone numbers etc.
I must to design a search engine with the filter criteria, that can be defined by a user. Those criteria would be created on the web site as key value pairs and saved in the database.
No rules exists to create such key value pairs. For example: FXXX would be some key with the value "foo".

Then there is a REST API, that contains the array of json objects as key value pairs again.

For example the key would be FXXX with value "foo".

Currently i know how do to match the objects from REST Call with saved objects.

But i dont have any idea right now, how do to filter some group of repair stations using the filter criteria the defined by some user, if these criteria have no rules...

And how to reference that criteria by some group of repair stations.

Thank you for the help

Comment: I don't get it. Who, and when, defines how the new filter criteria act on the old database entries? Is this in fact the question being asked?

Comment: Also, the "there are no rules" looks like an exaggeration. If the filters are usable on the data, there __will be__ rules about how the filters filter the data. These rules might just be enough.

Comment: 1.Some user has an access to a web application.
2. That user defines the key value pairs on the table and then saves these pairs. I dont know how to build a relation between these filter criteria with the groups of repair stations, that also saved in the database

Comment: Currently i have my doubts wether filter criteria would be usable on the data set ( groups of repairs stations), because i dont know how to link the key value pairs, that defined by some user with some group containing repair stations

Comment: To better understand the issue: ignoring the security problems (i.e. SQL injection), would a value containing a SQL WHERE clause defined by the user correspond to your objective ?

Comment: The value may be anything...including SQL Statements, any symbols and another things. But meantime i find that Idea with any values without any rules not effective

Comment: One option is to allow the user to specify code that would be dynamically compiled. But, as it is difficult to restrict the possibilities/permissions of user defined code,  security issued are nearly impossible to address.

Answer (score 0):

Today I proposed an another method to search, because this approach with any keys and values will be never working